# Ctrl + K, Ctrl + S (Surround With) -> #region is added a pragma declaration

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

Starting in VS2015 if I do a `Surround With` → `#region` snippet it creates this syntax:

```
#pragma region MyRegion 

#pragma endregion
```

Whereas before, in VS2013 and earlier it would do this:

```
#region MyRegion

#endregion
```

Any idea how I can change this to be the pragma-less version?